# sbt build failed - module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5

Tags: java, scala, web, sbt

I'm unsuccessfully trying to adjust sbt build for the existiing Scala project which previously worked fine but any docs was left. It seems that incorrect URL is substituted to resolve dependancy for "sbt.jar"...

Inside **my_project** dir:

```
ear
    application.xml
    web-logic-application.xml
project
    target
      config-classes
        *.class
src
    main
      java
        package(java-utils)
      scala
        package(scala)
        my_app.properties
        spring.xml
        ...
      webapp
        WEB-INF
          web.xml
    test
      scala
      resources
 build.sbt
```

**my_project/build.sbt**:

```
name := "my_project"

organization := "my.app"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"
...
libraryDependencies += ...
```

**C:\Users\svc\ .sbt\repositories**:

```
[repositories]
local

maven-central

typesafe: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/

typesafe-snapshots: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/
```

**C:\Users\svc\ .sbt\0.13.5\plugins\plugins.sbt**:

```
resolvers += "typesave" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.4.2")
```

**C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt** (wasn't changed after sbt installation on local PC):

```
# Set the java args to high */

-Xmx512M

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m



# Set the extra SBT options */

-Dsbt.log.format=true
```

Log shows:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.5 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\svc\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.5\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5!sbt.jar:

      C:\Users\svc\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.5\jars\sbt.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5!sbt.jar:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar

    ==== typesafe: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5!sbt.jar:

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom

    Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar

    Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom

    Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar
...
```

Really - I can see "sbt" over http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/jars/sbt.jar 
but it is absent over URL is generated by framework:

over http ://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar 
or over http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar

Can anybody suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest workable variant.

**my_project\build.sbt** looks like that:

```
name := "my_project"

organization := "my.app"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

resolvers ++= Seq[sbt.Resolver](
    "Local Maven Repository@wildfly" at "file:///M:/",
    "Local Maven Repository@common" at "file:///" + Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.m2/repository"
)

seq(webSettings :_*)
...
libraryDependencies += ...
```

**C:\Users\svc\ .sbt\repositories** - removed

Placed **sbt-launch.jar** in **C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin**

Placed **build.properties** in the **my_project/project** folder with that line inside:

```
sbt.version=0.13.6
```

(what version is - doesn't matter, it works with any 0.13.~ version - I checked)

Placed **plugins.sbt** in the **C:\Users\svc.sbt\0.13\plugins** folder with that lines inside:

```
resolvers += "typesave" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.3.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.4.2")
```

Removed **C:\Users\svc\ .sbt\0.13.5**

Placed **sbtconfig.txt** in **C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf** directory with that lines inside:

```
# Set the java args to high
-Xms1G
-Xmx2G
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
# Set the extra SBT options
-DproxySet=true
-Dsbt.log.format=true

#-Dhttp.proxyHost=my-proxy-in.com
#-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
#-Dhttps.proxyHost=my-proxy-in.com
#-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
#-Dhttp.proxyUser=my_user
#-Dhttp.proxyPassword="my_psw"

-Dhttp.proxyHost=my-proxy-out.com
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=my-proxy-out.com
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

In case of some artefacts placed in corporate closed network (as it is for me) you should run **sbt** twice - with 2 different proxies (commented/uncommented).

Answer (score 18):

Try to install ssl certificates. You can try using the command below. It helped me to solve the same issue. (Ubuntu 15.04)

```
update-ca-certificates -f
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. An explanation would be useful.

Comment: what's the equivalent for windows?

Answer (score 6):

Did you try to remove the `~/.sbt/repositories` file? The defaults should be enough.

If this still not work, try to update your sbt launcher to the last version.

Also a [good practice](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html#setting-the-sbt-version) is to have a file `build.properties` in the `my_project/project` directory with that line inside:

```
sbt.version=0.13.6
```

This will enforce the sbt version for the project, instead of using the version of the launcher.

Comment: Only removing `build.properties` didn't help. And after creating `my_project/project` with `sbt.version=0.13.6` artefacts started downloading. Thank you!
Unfortunately this was first barrier... Will post final result.

Comment: Removing the `~/.sbt/repositories` can be very helpful. I was facing a similar issue where it turned out our Nexus repository was improperly configured. By removing the repositories file you can be certain the Typesafe repositories are accessed for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

SBT 0.13.5 doesn't use the https repository by default. 0.13.6 does. In order to upgrade (since the server now requires it), you must set the repository in `repositories` on your system. On a Unix system it can be set according in `~/.sbt/repositories` to

```
[repositories] 
maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

According to the SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61350773/361855