# Access maven repo over https in sbt

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I have a java project which uses sbt(scala) for build. Up until yesterday this was working, but today I am seeing an issue in pulling a repo from maven

```
esolving org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-component-api;1.0-alpha-16 ...

[error] SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.pom

[warn]  module not found: org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-component-api;1.0-alpha-16

[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/ivys/ivy.xml

[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried

[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/ivys/ivy.xml

[warn] ==== local: tried

[warn]   /root/.ivy2/local/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/ivys/ivy.xml

[warn] ==== activator-local: tried

[warn]   file:/heimdall/app/projects/load-test/content-engine/repository/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/ivys/ivy.xml

[warn] ==== public: tried

[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.pom

[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried

[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.pom

[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried

[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/ivys/ivy.xml

[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried

[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.pom
```

Based on what I could infer, the repo seems to have been moved to https endpoint. And pom file is available on https endpoint. The issue is that this is not a direct dependency in my project but coming transitively via some other dependency. How do I use https for this specific dependency?

I am using sbt version 0.13.5. I checked the [reference manual](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html) for it, and added **DefaultMavenRepository** explicitly in build.sbt

```
resolvers += DefaultMavenRepository
```

As per this official documentation, the DefaultMavenRepository points to secure endpoint. Before this, I had tried the following in build.sbt

```
resolvers += "Maven Repo" at  "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
```

and added

```
"org.codehaus.plexus" % "plexus-component-api" % "1.0-alpha-16",
```

as libraryDepdency explicitly in my build.sbt so that it can be cached and not come transitively where I may not have control over where it would be pulled from. But this also fails. I cleared both m2 and ivy2 caches

Comment: The problem is that when `sbt 0.13.5` was released, `repo1.maven.org/maven2/` did not have `https` support. I think you can try `resolvers -= DefaultMavenRepository` followed by `resolvers += "Maven Repo" at  "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"`.

Comment: As per documentation of 0.13, DefaultMavenRepository points to secure endpoint. And I tried what you suggested, but still same issue. My build.sbt has these new lines  ```resolvers += DefaultMavenRepository```

```resolvers += "Maven Repo" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"```

Comment: Default maven repo was moved to https in `0.13.6`. You can use that instead. Maven central used to be http only till this post -> https://max.computer/blog/how-to-take-over-the-computer-of-any-java-or-clojure-or-scala-developer/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by Sarvesh, the issue was that I was using sbt version 0.13.5. And DefaultMavenRepository started pointing to https endpoint from v0.13.6(the documentation does not mention this). After bumping up the version, I was able to pull all dependencies.

Answer (score 14):

Create a sbt configuration file `~/.sbt/repositories` and add the following config:

```
[repositories] 
maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

You can find more info here - https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html

Answer (score 9):

Check the links in sbt configruation file: ~/.sbt/repositories

Change the line  `maven-central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` to  `maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`

It fixes the downloading without sbt update

Comment: I needed to create ~/.sbt/repositories and add these lines: 
      [repositories]
      maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Comment: Not quite what @cnmuc wrote but almost. Create a file called "repositories" without extension under Users/<Your User>/.sbt. In there, add the following lines: "[repositories]  
maven-central: h t t p s :// repo1.maven.org/maven2/" without spaces between the https

Answer (score 3):

Add the following resolver to you build.sbt or sbt file:

```
resolvers += "Maven Central Server" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
```

And then add the following property to enable TLS 1.2 protocol, when executing sbt jar file:

(java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -jar dirname $0/sbt-launch-0.12.0.jar)

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Answer (score 2):

**For osx:**

- Open the terminal.
- cd into ./sbt (in my case /Users/your-user/.sbt)
- `touch repositories`
- `nano repositories`
- Paste the following (be sure to add a new line after [repositories]

[repositories] 
maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/