# Importing old Play 2.3.4 project into IntelliJ gives SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

When importing a Play project (Play 2.3.4, Scala 2.11.4, sbt 0.13.5) into IntelliJ IDEA I get the following error message:

`SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.11/jline-2.11.pom`

According to the latest [IntelliJ docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html), only Play versions 2.4 and later are supported. So I downloaded an old IntelliJ version from 2016 (2016.2.5), which should have worked because the project was in active development with this IDE version back then. After finding a [this article](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334) stating the Maven repo has deprecated http in favor of https, I'm not sure if the IntelliJ version mismatch is even the cause of this issue. However, the build was ok in 2016, and now I cannot fix this problem even if I create a settings.xml for Maven as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59936630/5375652)... I still get the same error. I also tried to enable the "Override" setting in IntelliJ->Preferences->Build->Build Tools->Maven->User Settings File and pointed it to a settings.xml copy in a different folder. In both IntelliJ versions (2019.3.3 and 2016.2.5) I installed the Scala plugin directly in the IDE.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get IntelliJ to use the mirrors from my custom settings.xml?

Comment: First using a recent version of your IDE is recommended..furthermore you should check if the build works on plain command line ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command-line already ran only by overriding the sbt repository as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60079797/5375652), IDE-based build still didn't recognize this file.
Finally solved it by bumping the sbt version at least one minor version up, to >=0.13.6 ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59765833/5375652)), from then on sbt itself uses a secure connection to the Maven repository.