# play command gives UnsupportedOperationException, no matter what arguments

Tags: scala, playframework

I type `play`, `play run`, `play help run`, or anything really (though I can run `play --version`), and I get

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Position.start on class scala.reflect.internal.util.OffsetPosition
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.Position.start(Position.scala:114)
    at sbt.internals.parser.SbtParser.sbt$internals$parser$SbtParser$$convertStatement$1(SbtParser.scala:148)
    at sbt.internals.parser.SbtParser$$anonfun$4.apply(SbtParser.scala:153)
    at sbt.internals.parser.SbtParser$$anonfun$4.apply(SbtParser.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.internals.parser.SbtParser.splitExpressions(SbtParser.scala:153)
    at sbt.internals.parser.SbtParser.<init>(SbtParser.scala:58)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.splitExpressions(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:226)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.parseConfiguration(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:69)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:106)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:712)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:717)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:716)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:716)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:723)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:723)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Load$.loadFiles$1(Load.scala:723)
    at sbt.Load$.discoverProjects(Load.scala:734)
    at sbt.Load$.discover$1(Load.scala:545)
    at sbt.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:574)
    at sbt.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:442)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:446)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:334)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:289)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:285)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:276)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:130)
    at sbt.GlobalPlugin$.build(GlobalPlugin.scala:33)
    at sbt.GlobalPlugin$.load(GlobalPlugin.scala:39)
    at sbt.Load$.loadGlobal(Load.scala:88)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultWithGlobal(Load.scala:63)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:34)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:481)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Position.start on class scala.reflect.internal.util.OffsetPosition
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

I've tried a couple different JVMs (1.8, 11) and I get the same.

I have Scala 2.13.6.

```
$ play --version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
sbt launcher version 0.13.0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's an ancient version of sbt and the Play Console was removed (afaict) with version 2.5.  I'd perhaps try upgrading sbt.

Comment: Upgrading sbt was hard. I was able to by setting the repository manually using https://stackoverflow.com/a/61350773/361855.

Comment: I was unable to use sbt 1.0.0 or 1.5.5, but I can use sbt 0.13.6. I still cannot run `play`. I now get the error "Unresolved Dependencies org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.6: not found", which seems really odd. But... since you mentioned Play Console was removed to your knowledge, I just decided to use `sbt run` instead. This works for me.